# potential leak of an object stored into ABMutableMultiValueRef in iOS

Tags: ios, addressbook

I am facing this type of warning when i analyze my code. I share my screenshot please anybody can suggest me?

[image]
 [image]

This is my warning. What i have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I got my answer

Before return NO just write this line

```
    if (thisPhones)
    {
        CFRelease(thisPhones);
    }
    return NO;
```